# Android sqliteOpenHelper onUpgrade replacing db with new one

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My application will **ship** with a sqlite database in its **assets** folder which will be **copied to databases folder** after launch.

Now my concern is when I release a new version of my application with the new **identical** sqlite database, will onUpgrade gets called? If so would it help to **delete** the current database and call oncreate ( which my copying of database function is called there) ?

**P.s**: Database does not contain any user data

**EDIT**: Here's my helper class to handle the database

```
public class Helper_Db extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String DB_NAME = "Test.sqlite";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 3;
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private SQLiteDatabase _db;
    private final Context _ctx;

    public Helper_Db(Context context) {
        super(context, null, null, 1);
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        _ctx = context;
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try
        {
            copyDatabase();
            Log.e("DATABASE", "Database created");
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            Log.e("DATABASE", io.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        _ctx.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }       

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream input = _ctx.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte [] buffer = new byte [1024];
        int length;
        while((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }

    public boolean openDatabase() throws SQLException
    {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        _db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, 
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return _db != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        if(_db != null)
        {
            _db.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

every database (SQlite) has internal user version (you may get it with PRAGMA user_version;). When you open in your code your database with

```
SQLiteDatabase db = db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(..)
```

you should then do something like

```
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        // update if needed
        if (dbVersion > db.getVersion()) {
            upgrade(db);

            // set database version to last one
            db.setVersion(dbVersion);
        }

        // end transaction
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

So upgrade is just on you.

I really suggest to check this helper class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html , which may do most of dirty work for you.

And to your question. If I understand correctly, I suggest to not overwrite existing database as it may already contains some users data right? If not, simply overwrite it. If yes, you'll have to update it in your code during first open.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank for your reply, I'm using that helper class already and no the database doesn't store any kind of user data so basically I wanna put the database for previous application version aside and copy the application's new version's shipped database into the databases folder(overwrite??) Is this onUpgrade function of the helper class gets called when the application is upgraded to newer version? Any directions for simply overwriting the database? thanx

Comment: onUpgrade is not called after upgrade of application. Check this constutor and it's description: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29 . Important is parameter 'version'.

Comment: Hmm if you just want to overwrite database after update of your application, I think best place should be as soon after start of app as possible. In this case, you may extend 'Application' class and there check if start of app is an update and if so, simply overwrite database file before you use SqliteOpenHelper to work with database. There is a lot of other posts with info how to extends Application class and how to check if app is updated (may suggest way thanks to storing parameters into SharedPreferences).